# Logging with Log4J2 via SLF4j in JBoss FUSE

Tags: logging, jboss, slf4j, log4j2, jbossfuse

I'm trying to implement logging in my OSGi bundles running in JBoss FUSE v6.2.0.

I've got the following JARs in my classpath:

```
log4j-api-2.4.1.jar
log4j-core-2.4.1.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
slf4j-ext-1.7.12.jar
```

My logging code looks like this:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(foo.class); 
logger.info("Hello World!");
```

Unfortunately, SLF4J seems to be routing the logging to the Log4j framework that exists within JBoss FUSE, instead of taking the Log4j2 framework I wish to use.

Does anyone have any recommendations on what I should do to make this work with Log4j2?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're planning to use Async Loggers you also need to add the Disruptor jar to the classpath.

Comment: @Remko I'm not specifically planning to use any Async loggers, so I'm not sure if I should be adding that JAR though?

Comment: Then you don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Fuse uses pax-logging with log4j by default.
To have it using log4j2 you have to tweak the fuse installation a little bit. The steps are defined here for logback. It would be the same thing for log4j:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/975013